# How to move forward to next from login button to agent information form?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, database-connectivity

I want to open agent form after clicking on the button login, which I can't understand.

I have a table named agent having attributes User_Name, Password, First_Name and Last_Name.

I take input from user in User_Name and Password for login. 
After matching the values, it must move to next form of agent and display information.

If it becomes true than proceed to agent information.

```
private void jButton1_LogInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Connection con = MyConnection.getConnection();
   PreparedStatement ps;

    try {


        ps=con.prepareStatement("Select * from agent WHERE User_Name = ? AND Password = ?");
        ps.setString(1, jTextField1_UserName.getText());
        ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword()));


        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


        String Name = jTextField1_UserName.getText();
        if(rs.next())
        {
        String First_Name = rs.getString("First_Name");
        if(Name.equals(First_Name))
        {
            Agent_Info ag_info = new Agent_Info();
            ag_info.setVisible(true);

            ag_info.pack();
            ag_info.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.dispose();
            //System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

What can I do for completion of this task?

Comment: You already have the username : `jTextField1_UserName.getText()`
However i see one mistake, String comparison in java is not supposed to be done by` ==` operator, it must be compared as `User_Name.equals(First_Name)`

Comment: Please paste your stack trace into the question, that would make things easier to understand